# I have trouble with FTX api

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I want to get my balance using the FTX api.

Refer to the Python sample code in the [api docs](https://docs.ftx.com/?python#authentication) and change it as follows.

But it returns an error message.

**{"success":false,"error":"Not logged in: Invalid signature"}**

I don't know why the signature is wrong.

Can someone please help?

```
import json
import hmac
import time
import requests

# API Keys
with open('../json/api.json', 'r') as f:
    api = json.load(f)
    accessKey = api['FTX']['ACCESS']
    secretKey = api['FTX']['SECRET']

endpoint = 'https://ftx.com/api'
url = '/wallet/balances'
method = 'GET'

ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
signature_payload = f'{ts}{method}{url}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new(secretKey.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

headers = {
    'FTX-KEY': accessKey,
    'FTX-SIGN': signature,
    'FTX-TS': str(ts)
}

res = requests.request(method, endpoint+url, headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

## Reference

[FTX API Authentication](https://docs.ftx.com/?python#authentication)
[FTX API Get Balance](https://docs.ftx.com/?python#get-balances)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url to ftx.us
and the headers to

```
'FTXUS-KEY': accessKey,
'FTXUS-SIGN': signature,
'FTXUS-TS': str(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
signature_payload = f'{ts}{method}{url}'.encode()
```

Where the URL would look like => `/api/wallet/balances`

You need to include `/api` in your URL.